# A directional light doesn't adapt to the scale of a three.js object

Tags: three.js

I have a `DirectionalLight` as a child of a `Object3D`. When I set the scale on the object the light doesn't respond as I'd expect -- it casts a different shadow at a different depth. It's as though the light hasn't really been updated for the scale.

Is there something I must to do to get the light to properly scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DirectionalLight`s are not intended to be scaled -- or added as children of anything other than the scene.

three.js r.63

Comment: Oh, that's unfortunate, but at least I know not to try.

Comment: This is the answer to your question.